# How do I get iPhoto's facial recognition to stick?

Tags: photos.app

I worked with iPhoto for a while, tagging photos with faces. Now when I view my own faces, I see "Steven Fisher may be in 8 additional photos."

I click **Confirm Additional Faces**, then click to confirm each additional face. I click **Done**. There's no error message, but I still see "Steven Fisher may be in 8 additional photos." And when I click **Confirm Additional Faces**, I see the same eight photos.

I can repeat this over and over again. I've recursively changed the permissions on the photo library to 777, changed the owner, rebuilt the library (letting iPhoto change the permissions), but nothing's helped. I once fixed this by completely deleting the library, re-adding all the photos to it, but it died again within a few weeks (and, of course, I lost a ton of metadata I'll never get back). What else could be wrong?

Comment: Is iPhoto reporting any errors to /Applications/Utilities/Console.app?

Comment: No, nothing from iPhoto in Console at all.

Comment: I have the same problem. It only appears in a *huge* iPhoto library (more than 15K pics) and hasn't yet appeared in a smaller (~1K) library.

Comment: I have about 9k photos, which I never considered "huge." But I guess it's closer in magnitude to 15K than 1K. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It didn't happen to me with the latest version of iPhoto yet. But the only solution I found to fix this kind of issues in iPhoto '09 without trashing the entire iPhoto library was to remove only the Faces related files. With the '11 version the procedure would be:

- Close iPhoto
- Find your iPhoto library
- Right click on the photo library and chose "Show Package Content"

[image: Show Package Content on your iPhoto library]

- Navigate to the `Database` directory

[image: Navigate to Database]

---

**Edit**: If you save your iPhoto library regularly you can restore the files instead of deleting them. To open the iPhoto bundle in Time Machine follow the instructions in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45023/11600).

---

- Depending on your version of iPhoto you might have to right click on `Faces.db` and "Show Original"

[image: Show Original on the Faces.db link]

Delete the original `Faces.db` in the newly opened folder.

[image: Delete the Faces.db]

- Delete the 2 Faces files in the `Database` directory

[image: Delete the 2 Faces* files]

- Relaunch iPhoto
- Go to your Photos library

[image: Go to "Photos"]

- Select all the pictures (click on a picture then  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all pictures).
- Then in the "Photos" menu select "Detect Missing Faces"

[image]

You could also try removing only some of the files in the Faces directory before and relaunching iPhoto to check which file might be corrupted in your case.

Comment: This is more destructive than I'd like, obviously, but at least it keeps the other metadata intact. Thanks.

Comment: @StevenFisher I know, I am not entirely satisfied either... Good luck!

Comment: For whatever it's worth, these files seem to be part of a Time Machine backup. So it might be possible to fetch a version from before they became corrupted. I don't know how practical this is, but I'll try it next time.

Comment: @StevenFisher to retrieve the files from time machine there is a simple way to access the bundle, **[instructions are here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45023/11600)**.