# How do you access the content of the iPhoto bundle from Time Machine?

Tags: time-machine, photos.app, sparsebundle

I would like to access the files of the iPhoto library bundle to retrieve just some of the files to help solving [this question about corrupted iPhoto db files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33566/11600) properly.

In time machine mode there is no way to show the content of the bundle.

[image: No option to show the content of the bundle]

All I can get is a time machine view of the iPhoto application.

[image: Only option is to open iPhoto]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the iPhoto bundle ***before*** your enter Time Machine.
2. When you start Time Machine, the whole folder looks empty (plain white) - which is probably a bug that still needs a fix (I'm on 10.7.3).

   You can get to show the contents by toggling the view options.

BTW: It's also possible to use **Go to Folder...** via <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in Time Machine. But this will not help you to enter the iPhoto bundle - whatever the reason is :(

[image]

Comment: :D Both you and Coyote are Europeans?

Comment: You know what? I seldom use Time Machine... And for some reason I assumed you always started on he default folder... Thanks.

Comment: @CoffeeRain There are quite a few european here (i hope...) :)